# Point of change in the slope of the signal

Tags: python-3.x

Following is the graph which you get on plotting the given data points. There is an exact point where the slope changes before giving a stable line. What we have done is obtaining the first derivative and looking out for a point where the slope makes transition from positive to negative values. But for many data points,such a transition was not found. So is there a better method to do this?

How do you find that point (marked as a red circle in the graph) using slope in python?
[graph of the signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8zRm.png)

[-0.0006029533498891765, -0.0005180378648295125, -0.0004122940532457625, -0.0002953349889182749, -0.00018692087906219124, -0.00010093727469359659, -4.699724959278395e-05, -1.602178963390488e-05, -5.340596544722853e-07, 9.079014125876195e-06, 1.976020721514149e-05, 3.0441400304406785e-05, 3.845229512135229e-05, 4.3258832011533466e-05, 4.432695132046416e-05, 4.592913028383938e-05, 5.020160751956215e-05, 5.6076263718660146e-05, 5.9814681299896755e-05, 6.195091991774426e-05, 6.408715853560565e-05, 6.568933749899475e-05, 6.889369542577295e-05, 7.209805335256503e-05, 7.370023231594025e-05]

Comment: Whats the data you are providing? The data of the original points or of the derivative?

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo :This is the data of the original points, not the derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem requires some additional specification. The core question is what do you mean by "a stable line"? One potential definition is "consecutive line segments with the exact same slope." However, since the slope of each line segment is likely not precisely similar, this may not be helpful.

Another potential definition is "consecutive line segments whose slopes differ by less than a defined cut-off value." Whenever we're talking about a difference of slopes, we want to look at the second derivative. We can identify transition points by finding where the absolute value of the second derivative is less than the chosen cut-off value at each point.

The question then becomes, what cut-off value is acceptable? Since you want a method that classifies the 10th point as a transition point, I'll use that to inform the decision.

Here is code that defines a cut-off value and uses that to identify points with nearly similar slopes:

```
data = [-0.0006029533498891765, -0.0005180378648295125, -0.0004122940532457625, -0.0002953349889182749, -0.00018692087906219124, -0.00010093727469359659, -4.699724959278395e-05, -1.602178963390488e-05, -5.340596544722853e-07, 9.079014125876195e-06, 1.976020721514149e-05, 3.0441400304406785e-05, 3.845229512135229e-05, 4.3258832011533466e-05, 4.432695132046416e-05, 4.592913028383938e-05, 5.020160751956215e-05, 5.6076263718660146e-05, 5.9814681299896755e-05, 6.195091991774426e-05, 6.408715853560565e-05, 6.568933749899475e-05, 6.889369542577295e-05, 7.209805335256503e-05, 7.370023231594025e-05]
```

```
# Import required libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate figure
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('Data')
plt.plot(data)
plt.scatter(np.arange(len(data)), data)
plt.scatter(9, data[9], c='r') # Identify 10th point

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('First Derivative')
deriv1 = data - np.roll(data, -1) # Use simple difference to compute the derivative
deriv1 = deriv1[0:-1] # Remove the last point
plt.plot(deriv1)
plt.scatter(np.arange(len(deriv1)), deriv1)
plt.scatter(9, deriv1[9], c='r') # Identify 10th point
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Plot of data and first derivative]

```
# Approximate second derivative
deriv2 = deriv1 - np.roll(deriv1, -1) # Use simple difference to compute the derivative
deriv2 = deriv2[0:-1] # Remove the last point

# Plot data
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('Second Derivative')
x = np.arange(len(deriv2))
plt.plot(deriv2)
plt.scatter(x, deriv2)
plt.scatter(9, y[9], c='r') # Identify 10th point

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Absolute Value of Second Derivative')
y = np.abs(deriv2)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(9, y[9], c='r') # Identify 10th point

# Correctly scale y axis
diff = max(y) - min(y)
scale = 0.1*diff
plt.ylim(min(y)-scale, max(y)+scale)

# Define cutoff value
cutoff = 1e-17

# Identify points where abs(deriv2) < cutoff
idx_filter = y <= cutoff
plt.axhline(y = cutoff, c='r', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(x[idx_filter], y[idx_filter], s=200, edgecolor='r', facecolor = '')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Plot of second derivative and absolute value of second derivative]

As it turns out, there ARE two line segments with precisely the same slope. The 10th point identifies the start of them. The following code finds that transition point concisely, and should work for data with exactly one such point. It can be adapted to find multiple transition points if needed.

```
# Compute the first derivative
deriv = data - np.roll(data, -1) # Use simple difference to compute the derivative
deriv = deriv[0:-1] # Remove the last point

# Compute the second derivative
deriv2 = deriv - np.roll(deriv, -1) # Use simple difference to compute the derivative
deriv2 = deriv2[0:-1] # Remove the last point

# Define cutoff value
cutoff = 1e-17

# Identify points where abs(deriv2) < cutoff
idx_filter = y <= cutoff
x_transition = int(x[idx_filter][0])
y_transition = data[x_transition]

print('Transition Point Index: '+str(x_transition))
print('Transition Point Value: '+str(y_transition))
print('Difference in slopes: {:.20f}'.format(deriv2[x_transition]))
```

```
>>> Transition Point Index: 9
>>> Transition Point Value: 9.079014125876195e-06
>>> Difference in slopes: 0.00000000000000000000
```

Since there were no x-values provided, the derivative approximation is simplified by assuming that the x-distance between each successive point is 1. Addition of x-data would require slight modifications to the derivative approximations, and another derivative approximation method may be more appropriate if the data is unevenly distributed along the x-axis.

Comment: Will try this out. And the x values are plotted at a difference of 4

Comment: Then all you need to do is divide by 4 in each of the derivative calculations, such as: deriv1 = (data - np.roll(data, -1)) / 4. If the x-difference is the same for all values, however, you don't need to include it, since it will just scale the slopes by the same amount, which won't affect the relative order of the difference between them.

Comment: Tried this out, for a few set of data , this doesn't seems to satisfy to obtain the exact point, there is some trouble with the cut off point. The data set is as follows:

Comment: data [-0.0007476835162487788, -0.0007466153969398481, -0.0007092312211274127, -0.0006633020908435455, -0.0005746481882026172, -0.0004560869449117544, -0.000336457582311947, -0.0002243050548746267, -0.00013137867499800338, -6.782557611685613e-05, -3.417981788567115e-05, -1.9760207215155368e-05, -1.1749312398209866e-05, -2.136238617847508e-06, 1.014713343479301e-05, 1.976020721514149e-05, 2.7237042377628584e-05, 2.8839221341017685e-05, 3.0441400304406785e-05, 3.0441400304406785e-05, 2.777110203210087e-05, 2.5634863414225606e-05, 2.5634863414225606e-05, 2.7237042377628584e-05]
cut off: .0000015

Comment: With the second set of data, if I set the cutoff point to exactly zero, the script identifies a single point: the 17th one, which has a value of 2.7237042377628584e-05. If that looks right to you, I would recommend using zero as the cutoff point. Out of curiosity, what is the source of this data, and what is the purpose of finding these cutoff points? It's interesting that there are a pair of line segments with exactly the same slope.